# Why my requested parameter doesn't update?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, unity-game-engine

I am doing a unity web request, that sends the selected bet to the server. It send the bet fine to the server but when I change the bet I get an error that says

undefined:1
0,1
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1

This example is when I try to change the bet from 0.1 to 0.5  Somehow the bet doesn't update and the period changes to comma. I am 90% sure this happens because the server side code is wrong, because I tested this out in the unity editor and it was sending the correct bet everytime. I
belive it is on the first lines of code so here it is:

```js
router.get('/:bet',async (req,res) =>{
    
    const parameter = JSON.parse(req.params.bet)
    
    const BET = parameter.bet
    req.session.bet = BET
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert something into JSON which is not a valid json that's why it is giving parsing issue

If you actually want to submit a large js object send it by `post` request method
`req.params.something` is only a standard way for doing like getting single doc from database and deleting it
You should try different approach either a `post` method or use `req.query`

Comment: But why does it work until I change the bet. When I console.log the req.params.bet it returns{"bet":0.10} but when I change it to 0.50 in the game and send the webRequest it returns that error.